# Array out of Bounds Exception when populating 2D Array maze

Tags: java, arrays, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

I am currently prepping to head into a Data Structures Course and as a result have begun reading on certain topics before hand. I am currently studying up on Stacks but have come across a problem.

I am currently coding a Maze App that uses stacks to auto-solve a maze. However, I am experiencing a problem when it comes populating the maze itself.

Code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Maze {
    private Square move;
    private char[][] maze;
    private SquareStack s;
    private String path = 
                 "C:\\Users\\Sigh\\workspace\\StegmannStackMaze\\maze.txt";
    private File file = new File(path);

public Maze(){
    s = new SquareStack();
    maze = new char[12][12];

}

public void getMaze() throws IOException{
    for (int row = 0; row < 12 ; ++row){ // Creates the left/right walls of the maze " |  | "
        maze[row][0] = '1';
        maze[row][11] = '1';
    }

    for ( int col = 0; col < 12 ; ++col){ // Creates upper and lower walls of the maze 
        maze[0][col] = '1';
        maze[11][col] = '1';
        }


Scanner filescan = new Scanner(path);
for( int row = 1; row <= 10 ; ++row){
    String line = filescan.nextLine();
    String delim = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = line.split(delim);

    for(int col = 1; col <= 10; ++col)
        maze[row][col] = tokens[col-1].charAt(0);
        }
filescan.close();
    }
```

}

Here is the .txt file

```
0 0 1 E 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

The Exception itself occurs at  this particular line once col = 2.

```
for(int col = 1; col <= 10; ++col)
    maze[row][col] = tokens[col-1].charAt(0);
    }
```

From what I gather, this line takes each token that is created and populates the column. However, I am not sure why I get a exception.

Thanks for reading and hopefully I can get some insight from you guys.

Comment: The error implies you are trying to access an index of an array which is larger than the size of the array. This is simple to debug by just adding print statements to the problem loop and seeing what index it breaks at

Answer (score 2):

Changes

```
   Scanner filescan = new Scanner(path);
```

to

```
    Scanner filescan = new Scanner(file);
```

The path is a `String` variable  rather than `File` instance.

Comment: All you had to do is add a simple `System.out.println(line);`

Comment: @JyCan12 Please accept the aristotll's answer, if your problem is solved. Cheers